# NSURLConnection, NSOperationQueue behaviour between IOS 5 and IOS6 - UI Freeze !! -

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsurlconnection, freeze, nsoperationqueue

I'm trying to implement a queuing mechanism for url downloads on IOS. For this I use
 NSURLConnection for the network access part, and I enqueue them into a static instance of  NSOperationQueue class (shared between UIControllers). When the download starts, I update a UI progress bar, using the callbacks from NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate. 
There is one UIControllerview, one UIView. The Queue is created at ViewLoad, and assigned to pointer defined as a UIControllerView property

```
//UIControllerView Code
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.myDownloadQueue = [NSOperationQueue sharedOperationQueue];   
    }
```

and the implementation follows the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356873/sharing-nsoperationqueue-across-view-controllers)

Download is started via a button, creating a new NSURLConnection, and dispatching it to the NSOperationQueue via SetDelegateQueue:

```
- (IBAction)startDownload:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *url = @"<myURL blablabl>";

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                     timeoutInterval:30];
    NSURLConnection *urlConn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
    [urlConn setDelegateQueue:self.myDownloadQueue];
    [urlConn start];
    NSLog(@"adding a new task for url %@",[[urlConn currentRequest] URL ]);
    //Sets the UI
    self.awProgress1.progress=0;
}
```

the UIViewController implements the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate protocol, for the methods

```
        @interface awViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate>
        @end
    ...snip....
        @implementation
        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didWriteData:(long long)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(long long)totalBytesWritten expectedTotalBytes:(long long)expectedTotalBytes
{snip.. updates the progress bar here using performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector()..
}
        - (void)connectionDidResumeDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection totalBytesWritten:(long long)totalBytesWritten expectedTotalBytes:(long long)expectedTotalBytes{...snip...}
        - (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL{....snip...}

        @end
```

On IOS6, the code works fine, The UI bar gets updated as the UIViewController receives the [connection didWriteData:] calls.
On IOS5 however, when the url is fully downloaded, the UI freezes....
Step by step debugging shows that in both case, the code reaches the IOS run time when downloading is over, ie it's not stuck somewhere in my code. 
The UI is fine during download, I can press buttons etc...

If I set the NSURLCOnnection to run in the main thread, ie by removing

```
[urlConn setDelegateQueue:self.myDownloadQueue];
[urlConn start];
```

Then the code works again on IOS5. But that 's not what I want, I want the download to be executed in a background thread.

What am I missing ? is there some housekeeping to be done Queue wise on IOS5 ? Really the problem seems to occur when the NSURLConnection completes, as the UI is fine during download.
thanks for your help !
-A
PS: Sample code is available, just didn't want to clutter the screen too much...

Comment: This sounds like a deadlock of some sort. You say that the UI completely freezes at the end of the download. If you pause your application in the debugger at that instant, what does the stack trace look like? Whatever method you're stuck in within the main thread might point to what's wrong here.

Comment: Hi Brad, I think I misused setDelegateQueue, and what I get isn't what I expected - running the nsurlconnection in a separate thread under the control of an nsoperationqueue... My stuff needs rework :) thanks !